# Get array of coordinates of all white pixels of separated objects on picture OpenCV Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I hava a image of white objects on black backgorund. How can I get array of coordinates of all white pixels of separated objects on picture? I am using OpenCV and Python.

If I have an matrix like this (1=255):

```
  m = np.array([
            [1,1,0,1,1],
            [1,1,0,1,1],
            [1,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1],
            [0,0,0,1,1],])
```

I should get matrix of coordinates like this:

```
[
[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0)]
[(0,3),(0,4),(1,3),(1,4)]
[(3,3),(3,4),(4,3),(4,4)]
]
```

I know there is a function `findContoures` (and I was using this: `cnts = cv2.findContours(m, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`) but it doesn't give me all coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Get contours and draw white filled contours on a black background, one contour at a time. For each contour on black, get a list of all pixel coordinates using np.argwhere().

Comment: Detect your objects using cv2.connectedComponents(). This will assign an identifying number to each pixel according to which group it is connected to. Then loop through your components using a combination of a counter and np.argwhere. This will give you the coordinates for all white pixels, separated by components(groups).

Answer (score 2):

I don't totally follow the structure of the expected output but [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) can probably do what you want. For example, this:

```
np.argwhere(m == 1)
```

Gives you this:

```py
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: You get the same from `np.argwhere(m==1)`. No need for transpose nor cast as array.

Comment: @fmw42 Much better idea, cheers! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider using `connectedComponents` instead of `findContoures`.